# Incorrect syntax near '%'. inside dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard, dynamic-sql

I just found out about dynamic SQL but when I add a wildcard like '%', I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '%'.

Here is the query:

```
declare @Filter varchar(50)
set @Filter = '2%'

exec ('select * from dbo.tbl_coa where acct_code like ' + @Filter)
```

Anyway to fix this or is it impossible with dynamic SQL?

Comment: single quotes are required around string literals.  i.e. looks like the resulting SQL text is "`acct_code like 2%`"  which is going to throw a syntax error. it looks like (guessing here) the intent is to execute a SQL statement "`acct_code like '2%'`"  notice the string literal `'2%'` is enclosed in single quotes. for debugging, consider outputting the generated SQL text and take that to a different client to test

Comment: I thought that setting the varchar includes the single quotes. Got confused but my problems have been solved. Thank you very much. I'll remember escaping single quotes in future.

Comment: I actually disagree with the close reason here. This isn't due to a typograhical error, it's because the OP is injecting. They should be parametrising. The problem isn't due to a typographcial error at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concating the string incorrectly.
You should fix it to `set @Filter = '''2%'''`, check the result below.
[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c0e2405523c7d6335f6ed422f3b243f)

```
declare @Filter varchar(50)
set @Filter = '''2%'''

print ('select * from dbo.tbl_coa where acct_code like ' + @Filter)
// Output: select * from dbo.tbl_coa where acct_code like '2%'
```

[Full Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9a29e4c35a9ac96a15d0b902637b2db5)

```
create table tbl_coa(
   acct_code varchar(10)
)

insert into tbl_coa
values('21'),('20'),('30')

declare @Filter varchar(50)
set @Filter = '''2%'''

exec  ('select * from dbo.tbl_coa where acct_code like ' + @Filter)
```

**Output**

```
acct_code
21
20
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose `@Filter` in quotes:

```
exec ('select * from dbo.tbl_coa where acct_code like ''' + @Filter + '''')
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/16fc7/1)

Note it is better to put the needed quotes into the query that you execute so that if you do something like

```
set @Filter = (SELECT ... )
```

The query will still work without having to do something like

```
set @Filter = concat('''', (select '2%'), '''')
```